# Add GET based search arguments to url with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get, apache2

I am working on a cms that uses mod_rewrite to provide provide pretty URLs. The basic use case just takes any path and rewrites it to individual GET arguments, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)[/]?$ index.php?p1=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)[/]?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)[/]?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)[/]?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)[/]?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4&p5=$5 [L]
```

I also have a search form that sends GET requests, but I am not sure how to add this to the rewrite rules. For example:

http://site.domain/search?query=abc

should rewrite to:

http://site.domain/index.php?p1=search&query=abc

I have attempted the following, with some variations, but the search arguments do not appear in $_GET as expexted:

```
RewriteRule ^search?(.+)[/]?$ index.php?p1=search$1[L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all `[L]` for `[L,QSA]`

> **QSA|qsappend** When the replacement URI contains a query string, the
>   default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query
>   string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA]
>   flag causes the query strings to be combined.
>   http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html